# PHP - concatenate string from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, concatenation

i have string to send email registration.
this string is stored in database.

when i load the string with my model.

```
//string from db
Hi {$email} , bla bla bla
```

**my controllers example.**

```
  some function (){
      $text = $this->Some_model->get_string();

      // this var get from post
      $email = 'foo@mail.com'
      echo $text;
  }
```

and there is no change whatsoever in the string.
with str_replace i cant get the output like this.

*Hi foo@mail.com, bla bla bla*

what if my case. i have two or more string to replace?

example

```
 Hi {$email}, this is your {$username}
```

Comment: what does `$email` contain? when you get from db table

Comment: Something like this?
`str_replace("{$email}", $email, $dbstring);`

Comment: well you question is quite unclear

Comment: I suppose the string "Hi {$email}, bla bla bla" was used in double quotes, so the variable $email is automatically used as a variable not part of text, but in this case You are using this text in single quotes, so that makes the problem.

Comment: no, i am sorry. but if my case i have more than two string to replace.
example "Hi {$email}, this is your {$username}". should i loop the str_replace? i forgot explain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesnt magically check each string if it contains code it can execute. If your string in the database actually contains `Hi {$email} , bla bla bla` then PHP will just leave it like that.

So you need to manually override the values in the string to match the actually values. The safest way would be a simple `str_replace`

```
<?php
$string = 'Hi {$email} , bla bla bla';
$email = 'foo@example.com';
$output = str_replace('{$email}', $email, $string);
$output = str_replace('{$username}', $username, $output );
echo $output;
//Hi foo@example.com , bla bla bla
?>
```

Or in your code

```
<?php
some function (){
    $text = $this->Some_model->get_string();
    $email = 'foo@mail.com';
    echo str_replace('{$username}', $username, str_replace('{$email}', $email, $text));
   //Hi foo@mail.com , bla bla bla
}
?>
```

If you create the string (with double quotes) before you put in the database, the value of `{$email}` would have been changed

```
<?php
$email = 'foo@mail.com';
$text = "Hi {$email} , bla bla bla"; //notice the double quotes, single qoutes wont work
echo $text;
//Hi foo@mail.com , bla bla bla
?>
```

Comment: thanks hugo, what if in my case i have more than two string to replace?
example "Hi {$email}, this is your {username}". if I had to do looping str_replace?

Comment: If its two (or just a few) i would just use `str_replace('{$username}', $username, str_replace('{$email}', $email, $text););`. or seperate them with the `$output` and call them one ofter the other. If you would have a lot of variables you could start thinking about other options

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your function should have been like this assuming you have string like this 'test'

```
function get_email_string(){
      $text = $this->Some_model->get_string();
      $email = '@mail.com'
      echo $text.$email;
}
```

Output

```
test@mail.com
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants something that will replace the `{$email}` in $text with the value of `$email`. Though it's not the best-written question.

Answer (score 0):

That way is not correct...You can do like this.

```
function emailString(){
  $text = "Hi __EMAIL__  , bla bla bla";

   $text = str_replace('__EMAIL__','foo@mail.com');
  echo $text;
```

}

Comment: Why this is a correct way and not `{$email}` ? Will you explain please.

Comment: because you cannot call variable in string.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `$text` is `Hi {$email} , bla bla bla` since you wrote `//string from db` you can use [**`str_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to have your desired output

```
$email = 'foo@mail.com'
echo str_replace('{$email}', $email, $text);
```

this will out

```
Hi foo@mail.com , bla bla bla
```